# Fetch text from url then stringify it

Tags: javascript, fetch

So i have just started to learn javascript today and i'm trying to fetch text from a url and then split and stringify it using josn.

Then i'm trying to pick a random proxy from the stringify json and log it in my self invoking function but it logs as undefined and i can't workout what i'm doing wrong and i was hoping maybe someone could tell me what i'm doing wrong.

**My code:**

```
const doFetch = async () => {
  try {
    let proxies = [];
    let socks = await fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheSpeedX/PROXY-List/master/socks4.txt");
    let response = await socks.text();

    let list = response.toString().split('\n');
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      let splitText = list[i].split(':');
      proxies.push(JSON.stringify({'type': 'socks4', 'ip': splitText[0], 'port': splitText[1]}));
    }

    return proxies
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('fetch error:', error.message);
  }
}

(async () => {
  let proxies = await doFetch();
  let proxie = proxies[Math.floor(Math.random() * proxies.length)];
  console.log(proxie); // logs fine
  console.log(proxie.type,  proxie.ip, proxie.port);  // logs as undefined
})();
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify` will take an object *and convert it to a string*. You're then trying to access non-existing properties from strings.

Comment: You either need to parse your json back to an object via `JSON.parse` or remove the `JSON.stringify` call altogether

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`proxie.type,  proxie.ip, proxie.port` are undefined because `proxie` is a string and not an object. Rewrite your code in this way:

```
(async () => {
  let proxies = await doFetch();
  let proxie = proxies[Math.floor(Math.random() * proxies.length)];
  console.log(proxie); // logs fine
  let proxieObj = JSON.parse(proxie);
  console.log(proxieObj.type,  proxieObj.ip, proxieObj.port);
})();
```